# Question about the poly-Euler preprint

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, statistics

I'm looking over the preprint on poly-Euler numbers, and I think there might be a typographical error on the third line because $j=0$ leads to a discontinuity.

Could somebody explain the substation he is using?

[image: poly-Euler equation]

Comment: " the preprint on poly-Euler numbers" What preprint on poly-Euler numbers?

Comment: Sure thing. The proof for theorem 4. http://depmath.ulbsibiu.ro/genmath/gm/vol20nr2-3/paper_09/paper_09.pdf